# SED Variable contains Dollar Sign

Tags: linux, sed

I m having difficulty with sed, a variable contains Dollar Sign like this...

```
PASSWORD='AsecretPassword$'
```

I am trying to 'cleanse' and outputfile of a password with.

```
sed -i "s,$PASSWORD,ChangeMePassword,g" outputfile.json
```

I have tried every version of quotes you can imagine. please help.

Comment: I assume that it did not work as desired. Please elaborate. What result do you expect? Which result do you get?

Comment: What do you get for `echo $PASSWORD`? What do you get for `echo ${PASSWORD}`?

Comment: If I echo it I get the correct value. When I run the sed I get no changes, even though when I check the file I get output.  I have even gone as far as to.... `code` sed s/'"${PASSWORD)"'/Monday68\$/g" with no results

Comment: By both proposed ways?

Comment: What happens if you do `PASSWORD='AsecretPassword\$'`?  I.e. escape the dollar as you did in the code fragemtn in your comment.

Comment: I am trying to search for the variable contents in a file and replace them, it works if the varable doe NOT contain a dollar sign. but does not match if it does

Comment: Yes I understood that. So what happens if you do as I proposed?

Comment: I can't do that as the password is dynamic, I never know it so the sed command has to cope with special characters

Comment: Yes I understood that. The proposed experiment is for finding out the final solution. So what happens if you try?

Comment: Yes that works, I expected it to be so, thanks for helping

Comment: So what you need to do is to use your variable in a way that the system does the correct escaping for you. Sadly, I am not so fluent and currently do not have an environment to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let us suppose you have this file:

```
$ cat outputfile 
commonpassword
AsecretPassword$
abc123
```

If you had control over the value of the pattern, you could just escape the dollar sign:

```
$ sed 's,AsecretPassword\$,ChangeMe,g' outputfile
commonpassword
ChangeMe
abc123
```

Alas, we don't have, but we can use sed to escape the variable value:

```
 $ echo $PASSWORD | sed -e 's/\$/\\$/g'
 AsecretPassword\$
```

Fortunately, we can get the output of one command as part of another by using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
$ echo "Command substitution: $(echo $PASSWORD | sed -e 's/\$/\\$/g') Cool, right?"
Command substitution: AsecretPassword\$ Cool, right?
```

...so we just need to do it on our original command!

```
$ sed "s,$(echo $PASSWORD| sed -e 's/\$/\\&/g'),ChangeMe,g" outputfile
commonpassword
ChangeMe
abc123
```

In this case, we just escaped one special character. There are some more on sed, so [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) can be helpful in the general case.